# Verifying syntax - Java - Grammar - Regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, validation, junit

before I start explaining, let me state this is not a "please-do-my-homework" question. I'll post my code and assumptions or guessings, but I'm asking for your assistance as I wasn't able to solve this, and found this matter not only intriguing, but also a good opportunity to learn very useful skills.
This exercise is part of a homework task at my University, and deadline is already over. Why am I asking for help then? Well, the teachers will only provide the results score, but not the actual explanation on how to solve the exercise (it's the University policy) until the next period, the next year. I can't wait so long, I'm very intrigued on how to solve this.
This is a summary of the exercise speech: "there's certain isolated island in which they have their own language, but most people make syntax mistakes, so their governor decides to ask a developer to issue some piece of software which, observing their language rules, corrects the syntax".
And these are the rules:

1. The only characters in that language are the characters from 'g' to 'p' plus 'A', 'F', 'D', 'Q', 'X'.
2. Each character from 'g' to 'p' is a valid sentence.
3. If 's' is a valid sentence, then 'As' is valid too.
4. If 's' and 't' are valid sentences, then 'Fst', 'Dst', 'Qst' and 'Xst' are valid sentences as well.
5. Rules from 1 to 4 are the only valid rules to determine the correct syntax.

And this was not clear enough for many of us, so we asked the teacher about points 3 and 4, and he explained -as 's' is not actually a valid sentence, that was just an example- they wanted to mean that 'A' can be followed only by 1 lower case character, and F, D, Q and X can be followed only by 2 valid lower case caracters.

Alright, that may not sound so much complicated to a lot of you who know about regular expressions. Actually we weren't taught regular expressions, only JUnit -nothing to do with it? well, the thing is this exercise is actually part of a JUnit workshop, and yes, I'm as surprised as you-. Then, why am I bringing up the regular expresions subject? Well, the teacher commented that some student suggested him this exercise could be easily solved using regular expressions.

I'm developing in Java using NetBeans, and I will post the most important part of the code I have so far:

```
Pattern patronUno = Pattern.compile("[ghijklmnop]");
Pattern patronDos = Pattern.compile("A*[ghijklmnop]|A*");
Pattern patronTres = Pattern.compile("([FDQX]+([ghijklmnop]{2,2}))");
Pattern patronCuatro = Pattern.compile("[A][FDQX]");

public String validar(String sentencia){        
    Matcher coincidenciaUno = patronUno.matcher(sentencia);
    Matcher coincidenciaDos = patronDos.matcher(sentencia);
    Matcher coincidenciaTres = patronTres.matcher(sentencia);
    Matcher coincidenciaCuatro = patronCuatro.matcher(sentencia);

    if(coincidenciaUno.matches() || coincidenciaDos.matches() || 
                coincidenciaTres.matches() || coincidenciaCuatro.matches())
        return "YES";
    else
        return "NO";
}
```

And my first testing cases I have, pre-approved by the teachers, are:

Example IN  Example OUT

- Fg          NO
- Xij         YES
- AXij        YES
- Dklm        NO

Now, AXij is valid, because A is valid per sè, and Xij is also valid, so adding Xij to A is like adding a single one character valid sentence to it.
And that my friends, is the part of the exercise I haven't been able to deal with; as I couldn't learn -if there is a way to- how to join two valid sentences.
Could you help me on that part of the requirement?

With that code I posted, I'm getting these results:

Example IN    Example OUT

- Fg            NO
- Xij           YES
- AXij          NO
- Dklm          NO
- AAg           YES
- AA            YES
- Am            YES
- Amp           NO
- Amng          NO

I can't get AXij to be considered as a valid sentence, for example. However I could successfully validate Fx as invalid, Xij as valid, Dklm as invalid, etc.

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm posting this, as I've been searching through this website on examples that could explain this, but any of them was clear enough to me.

Comment: Not going to answer this, but using regex to validate a grammar looks like a very bad idea.

Comment: Really? I'm a complete newbie on regex, so that's why I may have done the wrong decision by deciding to use it. I know you said you are not going to answer this but, is there any suggestion you could make on what other path should I follow? I had started by combining characters in ArrayLists but I think that was like "brute forcing" the solution, and seemed like a not smart, so hard working out solution.

Comment: [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is the most well-known parser generator, although it might be overkill in your case. Otherwise try to lookup how to implement your own parser in Java, there's plenty of tutorials around. You might end up using regex for specific context-free instances, but using it for the whole grammar seems a short-sighted design choice. Been there :D

Comment: Even though I marked an answer as correct, I wanted to reply your comment just to say thank you, because disregarding the answer provided solved the problem, almost in 100%, I'm paying attention at what you said about ANTLR, as I said it before: deadline for this exercise is over, so my bet is to actually learn what suits best to grammar problems' contexts. I'll take a look at ANTLR then. Thanks a lot to all of you, people, you really helped me out and so I learned from your responses.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar you've described is quite simple and completely unambiguous so if you don't want to go as far as using a full-blown parser generator like antlr or JavaCC then a single recursive method like this could do the job:

```
public int consumeSentence(String str, int startOffset) {
  char c = str.charAt(startOffset);
  if(c >= 'g' && c <= 'p') {
    return 1;
  } else if(c == 'A') {
    // A<s>
    return 1 + consumeSentence(str, startOffset + 1);
  } else if(c == 'F' || c == 'D' || c == 'Q' || c == 'X') {
    // F<s><t>
    int s1 = consumeSentence(str, startOffset + 1); // s
    int s2 = consumeSentence(str, startOffset + 1 + s1); // t
    return 1 + s1 + s2;
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal sentence");
  }
}
```

This attempts to consume content from the string starting at a given location until it reaches the end of a valid sentence, returning the number of characters consumed.  To check if a string `s` is a valid sentence you call `consumeSentence(s, 0)` and see whether the return value equals the length of the original string.  If it returns anything less, or if it throws an exception, then the original string wasn't a valid sentence.

This is the kind of logic that a parser generator would build for you but this case is simple enough that you can code it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough theory knowledge to prove that this is context-free grammar. While regex flavors in the wild is known to match context-sensitive grammar, without recursive (Perl/PCRE) or balancing group (.NET), regex can't solve simple problems in context-free such as bracket balancing.

By the way, this is the grammar:

```
S -> 'g' | 'h' | ... | 'p'
S -> 'A'  S
S -> ( 'F' | 'D' | 'Q' | 'X' )  S  S
```

Usually, for such cases, it is better to write a parser. However, for toy problems, you can use regex to replace from the lowest level up and reduce the structure at the leaves `A[g-p]` or `[FDQX][g-p]{2}` to `g` (which represents a valid sentence).

```
public static boolean checkGrammar(String input) {
    String prev = input;
    while (!(input = input.replaceAll("A[g-p]|[FDQX][g-p]{2}", "g")).equals(prev)) {
        prev = input;
    }

    return input.matches("[g-p]");
}
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/W59PsZ)

Comment: Nice, though I'd probably use the equals() method to compare Strings in the while expression rather than relying on the JVM interning them. I don't think replaceAll() is guaranteed to return the original String if no changes are made, is it?

Comment: @BarrySW19: Thanks. That was an unintentional bug. I am using several languages, so I got confused.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure I understood everything, but this seems to match your examples :

```
^[A]?((A[g-p])|([FDQX][g-p]{2}))$
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/rU5nW2/1)

Comment: This is wrong. According to the rule `FDgpDgp` should be valid.

Comment: Hey! Almost did it! I couln't have figured that out. I ran that regex and found only one mistake: AA, according to what I understood from the exercise's requirements, should be valid. But that's something I have to check with the teacher, I'm not 100% sure. I'm going to mark your answer as solving it, because if AA should be valid, I'm sure a little adjustment in the could should do the trick, right?

Comment: I will carry on searching for @nhahtdh 's example ;) with conditionnal regexp

Comment: @nhahtdh you've got a point with that example. Maybe I rushed on marking this answer as solving the issue. I hope this doesn't discourage you and the rest of the people to keep on helping to find the exact final solution. I removed that mark just to allow more people to notice the question keeps open. Not that I don't value your great effort, Sly